# Retrieve String from values in HashMap at a specific occurrence of special character

Tags: java, split, hashmap, substring

So I'm trying retrieve specific substrings in values in a Hashmap constructed like this..

```
HashMap<ID, "Home > Recipe > Main Dish > Chicken > Chicken Breasts">
```

Which is passed from a different method that returns a HashMap

In above example, I need to retrieve Chicken.

Thus far, I have..

```
public static ArrayList<String> generalize() {
    HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> cats = new ArrayList<>();
    items = RecSys.readInItemProfile("PATH", 0, 1);
    for(String w : items.values()) {
        cats.add(w);
    }

    for(String w : cats) {

        int e = w.indexOf('>', 1 + w.indexOf('>', 1 + w.indexOf('>')));

        String k = w.substring(e+1);

        System.out.print(k);

        e = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("k" + cats);
    return cats;
}
```

Where I try to nullify String e for each iteration (I know it's redundant but it was just to test).

In my dataset, the first k-v pair is

```
3880=Home  >  Recipes  >  Main Dish  >  Pasta,
```

My output is

```
Pasta
```

Which is ok. If there are more than 3x ">", it'll return all following categories. Optimally it wouldn't do that, but it's ok if it does. However, further down the line, it (seemingly) randomly returns

```
Home > Recipe
```

Along with the rest of the data...
This happens at the 6th loop, I believe.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Edit:

To clarify, I have a .csv file containing 3 columns, whereas 2 are used in this function (ID and Category). These are passed to this function by a read method in another class.

What I need to do is extract a generalized description of each category, which in all cases is the third instance of category specification (that is, always between the third and fourth ">" in every k-v pair).

My idea was to simply put all values in an arraylist, and for every value extract a string from between the third and fourth ">".

Comment: Where is the HashMap in the code you posted?

Comment: I recommend normalizing your data, and _not_ storing strings the way you are.  Instead, maybe have each `ID` map to a set of strings.  Why are you storing your information this way?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're right. I completely forgot to include that the data is passed from a read method, which specifies what columns from a .csv file to extract. In this instance, 0 and 1 are passed as indexes (ID and Category)

Comment: When you say you need to retrieve "Chicken," what does that mean exactly?  If you add a more thorough problem statement to your question, it would help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added full code and a better problem description. Hope it clarifies

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following map:

```
Map<Integer, List> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] vals = new String[] { "HomeRecipe", "Main Dish", "Chicken",
    "Chicken Breasts" };
map.put(1, Arrays.asList(vals));
```

Then, if you need to find a given value in your original string using an `ID`, you can simply call `ArrayList#get()` at a certain position.  If you don't care at all about order, then a map of integers to sets might make more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can. change your data structure to a `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>` or `HashMap<Integer, String[]>`. It's better to store the categories (by `cats` you mean categories right?) in a collection instead of a string.

Then you can easily get the third item.

If this is not possible. You need to do some debugging. Start by printing every input and output pair and find out which input caused the unexpected output. Your `indexOf` method seems to work at first glance.

Alternatively, try this regex method:

```
String k = cats.replaceAll("(?:[^>]+\\s*>\\s*){3}([^>]+).*", "$1");
System.out.println(k);
```

The regex basically looks for a `xxx > yyy > zzz > aaa ...` pattern and replaces that pattern with `aaa` (whatever that is in the original string).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The data is parsed from a different method through a hashmap, however in my method all values are extracted and placed in an arraylist. Your regex gives me the same results, albeit with better formatting. Adding a replaceAll for Home, Recipe and > solves my problem, though I wish there was a "cleaner" way to do it.

Comment: @Sebastian then I suggest finding exactly which categories caused the unexpected string `k`.